# Can useReducer work with an array for state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've implemented a fairly simple means to add undo to `useReducer` with the following:

```
export const stateMiddleware = reducerFunc => {
  return function(state = { history: [] }, action) {
    return {
      history:
        action.type === UNDO
          ? drop(state.history) // lodash drop
          : [reducerFunc(state.history[0], action), ...state.history],
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(stateMiddleware(reducer), { history: [initialState] })
```

The `state` variable consists of the entire history so present state will have to be extracted from the first element.

I'm wondering whether `useReducer` will accept an array for the `state` parameter (and also welcome to comments on my approach - it avoids using what seem to be hefty packages to do something similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you some feedback on your general approach, I'll quote the Redux docs, as they provide many best practices about global state management. It makes switching easier, if you need a full blown store later on. I'll assume here that you want use the `useReducer` not just for one local component, but a more global state tree (thanks @DrewReese for the comment on this). If it's only about one component or so, your approach is perfectly fine!

Redux docs concerning basic state shape and wether an array is possible at the top level ([Link](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/basic-reducer-structure#basic-state-shape)):

> A Redux state usually has a plain Javascript object as the top of the state tree. (It is certainly possible to have another type of data instead, such as a single number, an array, or a specialized data structure, but most libraries assume that the top-level value is a plain object.) The most common way to organize data within that top-level object is to further divide data into sub-trees, where each top-level key represents some "domain" or "slice" of related data.

So basically, its OK, but other libraries could be possibly opiniated and expect an object, as it is by far the most likely choice.

If you implement this shape, be sure that your requirement is to *always* need an undo action for your *whole* state. Because it comes with a cost (besides mentioned 3rd party lib compatibility):

- adds one additional level of nesting directly at the top level
- scalability and granularity (see next point)

What, if your app gets really huge and you have hundreds of reducers. Each time, your action is dispatched, there will be a new state object put in the history array, which could get messy.
What, if you don't want a global undo, but a very fine granular one (in one particular reducer, say for one particular form element in the UI). You would have to distinguish between a global undo and a specific undo then. What instead about just one "UNDO" action which can be handled in each interested reducer in its own manner?

If that still fits your requirements, give it a try !

Cheers

Comment: FYI, OP did not ask about Redux, but instead asked about React's `useReducer` hook. You have a good answer, but to a different question. `useReducer` takes a reducer function (same signature as a Redux reducer) and an initial state value.  This isn't a top-level state tree, but rather a local component state tree.

Comment: Its correct, that OP did not ask about Redux. But I assumed that he wants to construct some sort of global store, as he mentions middleware in his code. And that seems to be overkill for a local component reducer.  In combination with React context `useReducer` *can* be a simple replacement for Redux store if you don't need all the tooling that comes with it. At last the Redux docs are good to quote from in terms of best practises, when there is a discussion about state management. But thanks for the hint, I'll update the answer to be more common.

Comment: Yup, no worries.

Answer (score 3):

If all you are really asking is if you can initialize `useReducer` hook state with a plain array, then yes, you can.

Example:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    ....
  }
};

function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    reducer,
    [] // <-- initial array value
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>State: {JSON.stringify(state)}</div>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          dispatch({ type: "add", data: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) })
        }
      >
        +
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "remove" })}>-</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit useReducer-with-array]

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible, but as [ford04](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5669456/ford04) pointed out it may not be a great idea for a variety of reasons.

The demo below shows it works to use a plain array as the `state` in `useReducer`.

```js
const initialState = [];

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return [...state, state.length + 1];
    case 'decrement':
      return [...state.slice(0, -1)];
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Counter() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        State: {state.join()}
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'increment'})}>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'decrement'})}>-</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```